# Unable to fetch actual data from HTML/Javascript using Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, splinter

I am working on my personal project , where I want to store stocks who made all time high and low.

Website as follows:

[image]

When I tried to fetch HTML , I got Javascripts , Jsons as page is getting render afterwords.

I got HTML like this :

```
function loadData(val){
    var url1 ; 
    if (val=='high'){
        url1 = '/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/json/online52NewHigh.json';
    }else{
        url1 = '/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/json/online52NewLow.json';
    }
    $.get(url1,
        function(data,curr){
             obj = eval('('+data+')');           

             maxPage= parseInt((obj.data.length)/ recordPerPage);

             if (((obj.data.length)%recordPerPage)>0){
                maxPage++;
             }
             setData(0);
        }
    );  
}
```

I am not sure how to get actual data , I tried **selenium , splinter ,urllib2** but does not worked in my case.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2,cookielib

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_new_high_low.htm'
file_name = 'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test.txt'


site= "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_new_high_low.htm"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)


conn = urlopen(req)
data = conn.read()
conn.close()

file = open(file_name,'wt')
file.write(data)
file.close()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('file:///'+file_name)
html = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
```

did I missed something ? Is there any other way to get javascript/json data after rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have browsable JSON, why are you mixing so many things? Your JSON path is fixed, so just use it directly

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2, cookielib
import json

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/json/online52NewHigh.json"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)

conn = urlopen(req)
data = conn.read()
conn.close()

data_json = json.loads(data)

print (data_json["data"][0]["symbol"])
```